# Accessing and/or modifying data from multiple resources at once in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm looking to create an input based on data from all records within a particular resource (not just a single one referenced by an ID present in the record currently being edited.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm working on a react-admin page for an app that deals with schedules. Each schedule has a list of time slots that are part of that schedule as well as a list of dates on which that schedule should apply. This is conceptually similar to a basic calendar.

I would like to give users a UI to select a list of dates that each schedule should apply, ideally presented as a calendar (but this isn't necessary). There are plenty of options to do this that are already available in react-admin, but none of them seem to provide me the ability to display dates that have already been assigned to other schedules as disabled/grayed out. This requires access all of the assigned dates for other schedules that aren't currently being edited.

Is there an existing way to do something like this in react-admin? or will I need to dig into the imlementation for `<ReferenceField>` to make my own version that doesn't need an ID for a record and just returns all records?

Comment: Hey, I might not have the answer to this exact question but I am also developing a scheduler using react-admin at the moment. Do you want to discuss further?

Comment: @EshaanGupta that would be awesome! My main challenge is getting it to work within the edit field of a single record, but that's looking pretty complicated. I could probably get away with a component that works like a <List> component that sits above the table of items in the schedule's list view, which seems to be how the enterprise <Calendar> works. Would love to hear about your usecase. I made a repo at https://github.com/MoralCode/ra-community-calendar with a discussions board to see if we are both after the same thing.